# Android - C2DM.jar file missing

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I am building fresh new project for Android with using C2DM. I cannot use

> import com.google.android.c2dm.C2DMessaging;

because I haven't added c2dm.jar file as a external library. Is it somewhere available for download?

Thanks

Comment: Check here: http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/source/browse/trunk/CloudTasks-Android/lib/?r=5

Comment: Is that library even necessary? C2DM is all string-based, you can implement it without any libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need the jar file or need to include it your code. All you need is to define a BroadcastReceiver to listen to com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE and com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION events and declare the receiver in your manifest.

Also need to add permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.shopholler.android.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Example of defining the receiver in the manifest.

```
<receiver android:name=".c2dmtest.C2DMMessageReceiver"
             android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" >
                </action>
                <category android:name="com.shopholler.android" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Note for C2DM to work you need Android 2.2 + market installed.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the code provided by Google. You can get it via the Google Eclipse plugin, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9228455/734687 for a detailled installation and also for a current caveeat.